# groupie adapter is not binding to recyclerView in app release but works in debug

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

im using kotlin for language and receive zero errors nor crashes when running the google play release version of my app for groupie. It simply will not load to recyclerView. Crash only occurs when Picasso is unable to load uri from firebase and my only reasoning for this I have gathered is since the adapter is null,  the image layout is null when Picasso is called in the adapter class my falt for not using a null check before calling Picasso, but I really have no clue as to why Groupie adapter works in debug version but not in the release version.
I have tried 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0' and 'com.xwray:groupie:2.1.0' with also implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.0.3' just to see if that was the cause but it was not.
I have tested while building my app with my own device(s) and emulators. all work perfectly in android studios. With the same device uninstalled the test version and installed release version 
and groupie will not fill the adapter like it will in test version

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "7.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.2"

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta03'

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'

implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0-alpha3'
```

}

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta03'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Also try updating groupie. Your groupie version and groupie kotlin extension version are different and may cause problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im putting this here so if anyone else might run into this foolish problem lol.

my issue was I was using an extremely old version of groupie.. 
If you need data binding then use version 'com.xwray:groupie:2.8.0'
which is the latest version with databinding included

The adapter class will look like this

```
  class Adapter(val somethin: Somethin): Item<GroupieViewHolder>(){
    override fun bind(groupieViewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {

         //some code

    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.the_layout
    }
}
```

then use this line in your activity above onCreate()

```
    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
```

Comment: Also to note I needed to change my ListItems from Item<> to BindableItem<BindingClass>

Answer (score -1):

This could be the result of [Obfuscation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#obfuscate),

try this.

```
release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: my app just updated on google play store applying this change and it did not change the result unfortunatley